# javascript [1,2,3,4,5,6,7] becomes 123, 234, 345, 456 etc

Tags: javascript

i like to ask for advise how to let this array [1,2,3,4, 5, 6, 7] to become 123, 234, 345, 456, 567?

this initial is a number 1234567, i split them

```js
const num = 1234567;
const result = String(num)
  .split("")
  .map((n, i, src) => (src.length !== i + 1 ? `${n}${src[i + 1]}` : null))
  .filter(Boolean)
  .map(Number);

console.log(result)
```

the result got 12, 23, 34, 45 etc.

how to make it become 123, 234, 345, 456?

thank you for help

Comment: but your initial number in the posted code is `1234`, what is really going on here?

Comment: It's only two digits because you make a string out of `${n}${src[i + 1]}` which is only two digits. What if you tried printing more digits?

Comment: hi, how to expand it to become more digits?  i tried +2, but it printed out same 2 digits only

Comment: Not _only_ `+2`: print _more_ digits: `${n}${src[i + 1]}${src[i + 2]}`...your result is supposed to have 3 digits in it. You end up with a different problem with the above code, though, only changing that.

Comment: ah i see,  i give it a try now,   thanks so much,

Comment: ya, it works now!,  thank Msanford for your help.  today i learn something  and you have made me  more knowledgable today, as i am very weak in RXJS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest solution will be to loop over the array and loop until `length - 2` as:

```js
const num = 1234567;
const strNum = String(num);
const result = [];

for (let i = 0; i < strNum.length - 2; ++i) {
  result.push(strNum.slice(i, i + 3));
}
console.log(result);
```

**`You can even create a generic function and get the result string of desired length`**

```js
const num = 1234567;
const strNum = String(num);

function getPartialString(str, len) {
  const result = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < strNum.length - (len - 1); ++i) {
    result.push(strNum.slice(i, i + len));
  }
  return result;
}
console.log(getPartialString(strNum, 3));
console.log(getPartialString(strNum, 4));
console.log(getPartialString(strNum, 5));
```

```css
/* This is not a part of answer. It is just to give the output full height. So IGNORE IT */
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: hi, deepk,  thank you very much, this also works!!!,   javascript got a few ways to make this happen,  in which nature would programmers select rxjs to apply the same? what will be your opinion?

Comment: @JeanValJean Sorry to say that I don't have `rxjs` knowledge, So I can't help you with that. Better to ask the question to one who knows `rxjs` better.

Comment: ya,  till now i am still blur blur about rxjs..... lol,  thanks decpk, and have a nice day!!!